"ImportError: Cannot Import 'solcx' Despite Manual Installation and Virtual Environment Setup"
ImportError: Cannot Import 'solcx' - Library Not Found
I'm facing persistent issues importing the solcx library in my Python script, and I'm receiving an error indicating that the library is not found despite multiple attempts to resolve the issue. Below are the details of the error, my troubleshooting steps, and what I need help with.
Error Message
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\sheik\demos\web3_py_simple_storage\deploy.py", line 4, in 
install_solc("0.6.0")
File "C:\Users\sheik\demos\web3_py_simple_storage\venv\lib\site-packages\solcx\install.py", line 501, in install_solc
raise exc
File "C:\Users\sheik\demos\web3_py_simple_storage\venv\lib\site-packages\solcx\install.py", line 494, in install_solc
_validate_installation(Version(base_version), solcx_binary_path=solcx_binary_path)
File "C:\Users\sheik\demos\web3_py_simple_storage\venv\lib\site-packages\solcx\install.py", line 700, in _validate_installation
raise SolcInstallationError(
solcx.exceptions.SolcInstallationError: Downloaded binary would not execute, or returned unexpected output.
Troubleshooting Steps Taken
**Manual Installation**: I tried installing the library manually using the command:

pip install py-solc-x
Virtual Environment: I created a virtual environment and installed solcx within it. I activated the virtual environment using:
venv\Scripts\activate
I verified the installation using:
pip show py-solc-x
Compatibility Issues: I attempted to use older versions of Python (e.g., Python 3.7) as I read that solc might not be compatible with newer Python versions.
Manual Path Specification: I also tried entering the path to solc.exe manually in my code, but it didn't resolve the issue.
Here is the relevant part of my Python code where the error occurs:
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc

# Install the required Solidity compiler version
install_solc("0.6.0")

# Read the Solidity file
with open("./SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()

# Compile the Solidity code
compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {
                    "*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.sourceMap"]
                }
            }
        },
    },
    solc_version="0.6.0",
)

# Print the compiled Solidity output
print(compiled_sol)

Additional Information
Python Version: 3.10.0
OS: OS build 19045.5011
Virtual Environment: C:\Users\sheik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\venv

What I Need Help With
Are there specific installation steps I might have missed for solcx?
What could be causing the ImportError even after multiple installation attempts?
Is there a reliable method to check if solc.exe is correctly recognized by solcx?

Any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!
